# linux kernel convert char * to uint8_t[6] (read string to mac)

Tags: c, linux, string, linux-kernel, type-conversion

I need to convert a string "00:11:22:33:44:55" to an uint8_t[6] representing a mac.
I tried on my own, read somewhere char can be casted to uint8_t, but I'm kinda exhausted to try on my own. :(

Maybe there is a function in the kernel which does what I want.

If not, here is my code, what do I do wrong?

```
char * cleaned_mac =NULL;
char * extractMac(unsigned char * shared_user_buffer, size_t offset) {
    char * buffer = kmalloc(17, GFP_KERNEL);
    cleaned_mac = kmalloc(13, GFP_KERNEL);
    int i = 0;
    strncpy(buffer, shared_user_buffer + offset, 17);
    printk("BUFFER [%s]\n", buffer);
    while (*buffer && i < 12) {
        if (isxdigit(*buffer)) {
            printk("BUFFER [%c]\n", *buffer);
            cleaned_mac[i] = *buffer;
            printk("CLEANED BUFFER [%c]\n", *cleaned_mac);
            i++;
        }
        ++buffer;
    }
    cleaned_mac[12]=0x00;
    printk("CLEANED BUFFER [%s]\n", cleaned_mac);
    return cleaned_mac;
}
```

calling it like:

```
uint8_t * mac;
mac = extractMac(shared_user_buffer, strlen(tmq_server_prefix));
printk(KERN_DEBUG "MAC[%s]\n", mac);

printk(KERN_DEBUG "MAC[%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x]\n", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
```

so when I give "08:00:27:19:1f:02" in the function the result is:

```
Oct 13 17:41:28 client2 kernel: [ 1953.179271] CLEANED BUFFER [080027191f02]
Oct 13 17:41:28 client2 kernel: [ 1953.179273] MAC[080027191f02]
Oct 13 17:41:28 client2 kernel: [ 1953.179276] MAC[30:38:30:30:32:37]
```

So 08 became 30 and 38 ? Why is that?

Solution inspired from Dave (thank you):

```
uint8_t * cleaned_mac = NULL;
uint8_t * extractMac(unsigned char * shared_user_buffer, size_t offset) {
    char *c;
    char * buffer = kmalloc(17, GFP_KERNEL);
    int p = 0;
    const char * sep = ":";
    cleaned_mac = kmalloc(ETH_ALEN * sizeof(uint8_t), GFP_KERNEL);
    strncpy(buffer, shared_user_buffer + offset, 17);

    while ((c = strsep(&buffer, sep))) {
        cleaned_mac[p++] = simple_strtol(c, NULL, 16);
    }
    return cleaned_mac;
}
```

Usage then:

```
uint8_t *  mac;
mac = extractMac(shared_user_buffer, strlen(tmq_server_prefix));
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "---------------MAC [%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x]\n",
                mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
```

Comment: the ascii code for '0' is `0x30`, and '8' is `0x38`. You seem to be running your hex converter in reverse, and forgetting that characters use ascii.

Comment: yeah but it should be 08, so why is mac[0] interpreted as '0' and not 0x08 ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't have the patience to understand what this extremely convoluted code is doing, but if `mac` is a character buffer containing "08:00:27:19:1f:02", then `mac[0]` will return '0'. I recommend reading about how strings work.

Comment: mac is an uint8_t * not a string.

Comment: There is nearly no difference. Important is what is contained in the buffer: raw data oder data in hex representation? Obviously the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokenize the string, and call `strtol` on each result

```
char *c;
int p = 0;
for(c=strtok(buffer, ",");c;c=strtok(NULL, ","))
     mac[p++] = strtol(c, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: That doesn't really work, since the MAC uses hexadecimal. `atoi` would give you the decimal interpretation, which is wrong.

Comment: Aah, I'll fix that with `strtol`

Comment: im in kernel, the functions you use are missng ther, but i got a solution. i post ist in my question.

Answer (score 4):

I can't decipher how your code is supposed to work, so I'll just write how I would do it:

```
char* macIn = "08:00:27:19:1f:02";
uint8_t macOut[6] = {0};

sscanf(macIn, "%2x:%2x:%2x:%2x:%2x:%2x", macOut, macOut+1, macOut+2, macOut+3, macOut+4, macOut+5);

printf("MAC IN: [%s]\n", macIn);
printf("MAC OUT (hex): [%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x]\n",
     macOut[0], macOut[1], macOut[2], macOut[3], macOut[4], macOut[5]);
printf("MAC OUT (decimal): [%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d]\n",
     macOut[0], macOut[1], macOut[2], macOut[3], macOut[4], macOut[5]);
```

Comment: didnt work. Printing was fine, but injecting it in an skb didn't work, was just garbage in there.

Comment: wtf is an skb? If printing worked, then you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: FYI: http://ftp.gnumonks.org/pub/doc/skb-doc.html As I just saw I used a wrong pointer, your solution is fine also

Answer (score 1):

The `%02x` printf format interprets `mac[0]` as an integer, and prints it out as a string by converting it to two-digit hex.

Since `mac[0]` holds the ASCII character `0`, whose ASCII code is 0x30, it's perfectly normal that you get the output you have.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take every pair of characters, verify that the are really in the range `'0'`..`'9'`, `'A'`..`'F'` or `'a'`..`'f'`. Then you take the first, map it to its "meaning" (0..15), multiply it with 16 and add the second one, mapped as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've encoutered the same problem, finally solved with this simple code, it is in linux kernel.

```
char *mac_local = "e4:95:6e:4e:ee:6c"; 
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    buffAssco[i+START_POS] = simple_strtol(mac_local+3*i,NULL,16)&0xff;
```

Answer (score 0):

The 11-year-old answer from Chriszuma is actually wrong.

Reading "%2x" to an uint8_t will result in some unintentional memory modification.

The right specifier to read hex value for uint8_t is "%hhx"

So the sscanf should be like this:

```
sscanf(macIn, "%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx", macOut, macOut+1, macOut+2, macOut+3, macOut+4, macOut+5);
```